# Issue while Implementing OnItemLongClickListener in MvxListView Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to Implement `LongClickListener` in my program but there are some issues

**Here is my code**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
    ...
    ...
    MvxListView mvxListView = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);
    mvxListView.OnItemLongClickListener = new IOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    ...
    ...}
```

and here I writen the `OnItemLongClickListener`

```
public class IOnItemLongClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Widget.AdapterView.IOnItemLongClickListener
    {
        private readonly OrderListView orderList;

        public IOnItemLongClickListener(OrderListView orderListView)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.orderList = orderListView;
        }

        void AdapterView.IOnItemLongClickListener.OnItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            clickPosition = position;
            orderList.ViewModel.ShowDetailCommand.Execute(orderList.ViewModel.OrderList[position]);
        }

    }
```

**but when I run the program then issue occurs that**

> 'AdapterView.IOnItemLongClickListener.OnItemLongClick' in explicit
>   interface declaration is not a member of interface
>
> 'Droid.Views.OrderListView.IOnItemLongClickListener' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'Android.Widget.AdapterView.IOnItemLongClickListener.OnItemLongClick(Android.Widget.AdapterView,
>   Android.Views.View, int, long)'

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are using `MvvmCross` as seen on your tag. Why are you not using `ItemLongClick` binding to your PCL?

Comment: I only want to open Popup on LongClick in Client side so why Implement in Core?

Comment: This defeats the MVVM pattern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way,
I had calling wrong function

```
MvxListView mvxListView = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);
mvxListView.OnItemLongClickListener = new onListClickListener(this);
```

...

```
public class onListClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Widget.AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener
    {
        //public AcceptedTaskFragment acceptedTaskFragment;
        private readonly OrderListView orderList;

        public onListClickListener(OrderListView orderListView)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.orderList = orderListView;
        }

        void AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener.OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            clickPosition = position;
            orderList.ViewModel.ShowDetailCommand.Execute(orderList.ViewModel.OrderList[position]);
        }

    }
```